# SOGo without Samba4 Active Directory

Tags: email, active-directory, samba4

I'm tinkering with SOGo groupware to be run on my homeserver. I'm especially interested in the ActiveSync capability to synchronize contacts and calendar of my Android devices without the need for CalDAV/CardDAV apps and optionally from Outlook 2013 and Thunderbird.

Configuration examples for SOGo on the net build upon a Samba4 Active Directory domain controller or LDAP for authentication. Since there will be likely only two users this seems like overkill and I quite frankly don't really get a hang on LDAP. In principle SOGo should support authenticating against a MySQL database according to the docs, but:

**Does ActiveSync/Outlook 2013 compatibility in SOGo require an Active Directory (via Samba4) or does it work with MySQL for authentication?**

Comment: Very interesting question, did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

no, don't needed. On sme server 9.1 + sogo3.0.2 there isn't samba 4 and EAS accounts work out of box, Outlook 2016 included.. But, you cannot use Outlook < 2013 due to unsupported EAS Account.